# Find interior of A

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have the following exercise:
Let $(X,d)$ be the metric space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$. Find the interior of $A$ and $B$ where
$A=\{(x,y), x=2\}$ and $=B\{(x,y), x=y^2\}$.

Comment: Surely the minus between the two squared terms should be a plus? Also, do you want the interior of the region between the two curves or of each curve individually? What have been your thoughts?

Comment: I want the interior of each curve seperately. I already proved that these are closed sets. I tried to calculate the boundary because I thought me may be have only boundary points but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Both A and B have empty interiors, since for every point in the set, there will be points outside A and B in every neighborhood of that point.